# How to cleanup and count bytearray's?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a `bytearray` buffer:

```
buffer = bytearray() #creates the buffer
```

My array should have 500 bytes size maximum.

What I want is:

After the buffer is filled with the 500 bytes, I want to cleanup the array and start appending again from the beginning.

```
if (buffer.count() >= 500) #ERROR!! count()
  buffer.clean()  #ERROR!! clean?!

buffer.append(10) #appends some value to the array
```

- How can I count the current array size? the `count()` needs a parameter, but in this example, what should be?

I know about [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214220/how-to-use-count-for-bytearray), but it was not clear how can I just count how many I have in my array. `b.count(b'a')`

- How can I clean up the array? Or how can I set the "pointer" to be in the beginning of the array again?

Comment: How about `len(buffer)` and `buffer.clear()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself / from comments - I can use the following:

- `len(buffer) # to have the length of the buffer`
- `del buffer[:] # for cleaning up the buffer`